# checking if output of a curl commnd is null or not in shell script

Tags: shell, curl, command-line, null

I am writing a shell script and the curl command is stored in a variable like this:

```
str="curl 'http...'"
```

and I am evaluating this using

eval $str

I want to check whether the output of this is null or not,means it is returning me something or not.How can I check this?
Why cant I store the output in a variable like this:

op=eval $str
Why does wriring this gives error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command substitution:

```
str="curl 'http...'"
op=$(eval "$str")
if [[ -n $op ]]; then
    echo "Output is not null."
else
    echo "Output is null.
fi
```

A better approach actually instead of using eval, is to use arrays as it's safer:

```
cmd=("curl" "http://...")
op=$("${cmd[@]}")
if [[ -n $op ]]; then
    echo "Output is not null."
else
    echo "Output is null.
fi
```

When assigning the array, separate every argument as a single element. You can pick any quoting method whether by the use of single quotes or double quotes if quoting is necessary to keep an argument as one complete argument.

By the way you simply had an error since it wasn't the proper way to call a command in which you'd get the output. As explained you have to use command substitution. An advanced method called process substitution could also be applicable but it's not practical for requirement.